# HTML5 Audio in Firefox 15

Tags: html, audio

I'm following this quick tutorial:

http://code.coneybeare.net/getting-html5-audio-tag-and-flash-fallback-to

In Firefox 15 both the OGG and MP3 files play, what am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="audio-player.js"></script>
            <script>  
                AudioPlayer.setup("player.swf", {  
                    width: 500,  
                    initialvolume: 100,  
                    transparentpagebg: "yes",  
                    left: "000000",  
                    lefticon: "FFFFFF",
                    animation: "no",
                    autostart: "yes",
                    noinfo: "yes"
                });  
            </script>  
      </head>
      <body>
      <audio id="audioplayer" preload controls autoplay="autoplay" loop style="width:424px;">
          <source src="emo.mp3">
          <source src="emo.ogg">
      </audio>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          var audioTag = document.createElement('audio');
          if (!(!!(audioTag.canPlayType) && ("no" != audioTag.canPlayType("audio/mpeg")) && ("" != audioTag.canPlayType("audio/mpeg")))) {
              AudioPlayer.embed("audioplayer", {soundFile: "emo.mp3"});
          }
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Link to us your site; the script looks fine from here, but without a live test we can't really do much.

Comment: www.timpiele.com/audio/test2.php